# wp_redirect() is giving a mixed content error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I recently moved my site over to https and everything is working, but a plugin that I am using to submit a form that is supposed to redirect on submit is not working.

It is using the wp_redirect() function in order to redirect it, but I am getting the following error in the console and the form does not submit

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.domain.com/form/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.domain.com/thankyou/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have HTTPS set in my general > settings and I believe I have the htaccess file set up correctly as everything else on the site seems to work correctly. Is there a way I can troubleshoot this or get it to start working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid full URLs and instead use relative paths for things like images, JS, CSS

```
<img src="http://fulldomain/folder/file">    will cause alerts when viewed via https

<img src="./folder/file">  will not cause alerts
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. The redirect happens in PHP like so

wp_redirect('https://google.com/search')

Comment: right, then the page you landed on with https references at least one thing via http..  View the source of /form/ on your site and look for http://

Comment: I don't get the error until I hit submit, so I don't think there is a hard-coded link, it might be some kind of ajax request? Im not really sure

Comment: Ok, look for "http" in the html souce of the thank you page then :)

Comment: sorry, I guess my point is, some code would be nice to look at, particularly the opening form tag, and the html from the file the form posts to